# Why is it enough to consider simple functions on open intervals to prove the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I was looking at the proof of the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma). I noticed that in their proof they assumed it was enough to show that it held for simple functions of the form:
$$\sum_{n=1}^m c_n\chi_{(a_n,b_n)}$$
before applying that simple functions are dense in $L^1$. But can't we have simple functions of the form $\sum_{n=1}^m c_n\chi_{E_n}$, where $E_n$ is a Borel set not necessarily an interval? How do we know the assertion holds for these simple functions?

Comment: The step functions are dense in $L^1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to look the fundamental properties of Lebesgue measure, in particular , the Lebesgue measure is regular. This means that for any Borel set $A$, their exists a sequence of open sets $(\mathcal U_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ such that 
$$\forall n\in \mathbb N, \quad\quad A \subset \mathcal U_n \text{ and } \lambda(\mathcal U_n\setminus A) \leq \frac{1}{n}.$$ 
This allows you to approximate in $L^1$ any simple function by step functions.

To conclude : 
$\{\text{Step functions}\}$ is dense in $\{\text{simple functions}\}$ which is dense in $L^1$